# Why is purgeCSS removing styles used by my React-Bootstrap app?

Tags: next.js, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5, purge

I am trying to purge unused styles from my app. But when purging it still removes used classes and the site looks broken.

I am using the following packages:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.0.3",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.3.4",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.1",
    "next": "^11.1.0",
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes": "^5.0.2",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.40.1"
  }
```

In the `./styles` folder I have a `layout.scss` where I import `@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";` as well. I am then importing `import "../styles/layout.scss";` in `_app.js`

I have created a `postcss.config.js` with the following:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    "postcss-flexbugs-fixes",
    [
      "postcss-preset-env",
      {
        autoprefixer: {
          flexbox: "no-2009",
        },
        stage: 3,
        features: {
          "custom-properties": false,
        },
      },
    ],
    [
      "@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss",
      {
        content: [
          "./pages/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./components/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
          "./node_modules/react-bootstrap/**/*.js",
        ],
        defaultExtractor: (content) => content.match(/[\w-/:]+(?<!:)/g) || [],
        safelist: ["html", "body"],
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

I have included `"./node_modules/react-bootstrap/**/*.js",` as well as recommended on an earlier post. This does help a little bit but still removes used classes by **react-bootstrap**.

I tried adding `css: ["./styles/**/*.scss, ./styles/**/*.css"]` in `postcss.config.js` as well, which seems to do nothing either.

With all that it still looks broken:

[image]

While it should look like this:

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap/issues/6059 there's a comment here that says purgeCSS wont work with react-bootstrap and that we'll need to explicity set the classNames ourselves.

Comment: Also there's this forum https://giters.com/FullHuman/purgecss/issues/491 that goes more into it in detail with a possible solution

Comment: @TigerCode I do not have any progress because I kind of moved on to MUI (Material UI). Your latest link does promise a solution, which would not be the perfect one, but at least something. I might test it upcoming week.

Answer (score 2):

This configured prop inside '@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss' plugin saved my modals in boostrap from purge, so I guess you need to add to the safelist the css prefix used in the exact boostrap component you need to maintain unpurged

```
safelist: {
            standard: ['html', 'body', 'btn'],
            deep: [/^col/, /^navbar/, /^nav/, , /^modal/]
          },
```